# Javascript animation WITHOUT jquery/settimeout/setinterval

Tags: javascript

As the title says.. is there any possible way to have the simplest of animations in javascript without the use of Jquery, settimeout, and setinterval. I've been researching for too long now and cannot find anything. There may not be a way to do it, just wondering. Looking for something cross browser as well, so CSS animations won't work either.

Comment: There's a crucial piece of the question missing: why are `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` a problem for you?

Comment: Why would you even want to do an animation WITHOUT jquery ?? It's probably the best/fastest/safest way to touch the DOM.

Comment: You could use an animated GIF - supported in all browsers and doesn't require any javascript at all.

Comment: @frenchie—other [libraries are faster](http://www.cinsoft.net/taskspeed.html) (as is plain js usually), there is nothing inherently "safe" about jQuery, and "best" is up to the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "correct" way to do most animations now is with `window.requestAnimationFrame`, which acts like a `setTimeout` in that it runs a callback function at a specified time.

It's optimized to run at 60fps, and in some browsers (FF) it will give you the exact number of milliseconds until the next draw so that you can very precisely calculate animation positions.

Google "requestAnimationFrame shim" for various cross-browser implementations for older browsers.  The shims all use `setTimeout` — there's no way around that.

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame` only works in some browsers (e.g. no version of IE before IE10, no version of Safari before 5.3, etc...).  See http://www.caniuse.com/#search=requestanimationFrame for details.  And, the work-arounds for older browsers all use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` so there's no way around that.  So, if you need it to work across browsers without timers, this answer does not solve that (because there is no solution).

Comment: @jfriend00 -- Isn't that what I said in my last sentence?  :)

Answer (score 1):

No, how can you do it without intervals/timeouts and be able to do it cross browser? You need something to keep triggering it.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you're animating something on user input. If you animate something when the user triggers mouse move events, or page scroll events, it could work, but it would be stop-and-go, and 100% dependent on the user triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is any way of making a pause in javascript without using `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

The only option I can think of would be to have javascript wait for some event like an XMLHttpRequest object response, which is beyond ridiculous.

If you're looking for some convenient "pause execution for (x) milliseconds and continue" like `Thread.sleep()` in JavaScript or `usleep()` on Unix systems, there is no such thing sadly.

I remember hearing that for timing purposes on a Ruby script, running in Google Sketchup, someone went to the trouble of making an invisible HTML window just to run a little JavaScript using `setInterval()` so they would have a timing mechanism. I think if you go to such lengths to run JavaScript and still use `setInterval()` there probably is no other option.